# How do I get the list of SHA values of all the files in a folder of my git repo using JGit library

Tags: java, git, jgit, git-ls-files

I believe that I can get the SHA values of all the files in a folder through command line by using `git ls-files -s <file name>` command. I want to know if there is an equivalent way in JGit Java library?

PS: I don't want to calculate SHA of files myself and there can be many files inside the folder so I need to get SHAs which are already present in git objects. Also, I can't do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git ls-files -s")` as the host machine will not identify `git` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the object IDs of the index, you can use the `DirCache` as it is called in JGit. It allows to iterate over its entries.

The following example prints the object ID of each file in the index:

```java
DirCache index = repository.lockDirCache();
for (int i = 0; i < index.getEntryCount(); i++) {
  DirCacheEntry entry = index.getEntry(i);
  System.out.println(entry.getObjectId().getName() + " " + entry.getPathString());
}
```